# Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme' when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tailwind-css

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 7 app to Heroku but it fails on `Running: rake assets:precompile` with error: `Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme' when deploying to Heroku`

I tried running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but it didn't help.

I am using `gem "tailwindcss-rails", "~> 2.0"` to add TailwindCSS to my Rails app.

It works locally when I run it with `bin/dev`(or `rails s` after running `bin/dev`).

Am I missing some crucial step here?

Here is my `tailwind.config.js` for reference.

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*',
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
      colors: {
        primary: "#000000",
        action: "#000000",
        "action-hover": "#000000"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found out that Heroku didn't run `npm install` because it recognized it only as a Ruby app so it had only `heroku/ruby` buildpack.

I had to add `herok/nodejs` buildpack as well so it runs `npm install`. **Note**: Also that `heroku/nodejs` buildpack has to be on the 1st place on `heroku buildpacks`(command)

I added it with `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs`. But make sure it doesn't override Ruby buildpack so if it does just add it back.

So in the end `heroku buildpacks` command has to look like this:

```
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this! It helped me get around a similar problem.

My Rails 7 app, created with the `--css tailwind` option, was working just fine on Heroku. But things got weird when I added a custom Tailwind plugin that used the `flattenColorPalette` utility:

```
...
function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
  matchUtilities(
    {
      "solid-bottom-line-2": (value) => ({
        "boxShadow": `0 2px 0 0 ${value}`
      })
    },
    {
      "values": flattenColorPalette(theme("backgroundColor")),
      "type": "color"
    }
  )
}
...
```

I had to import that utility in my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
const {
  default: flattenColorPalette,
} = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette')
```

After that, things blew up locally. Using the bundled standalone executable that comes with the `tailwindcss-rails` gem wasn't sufficient once I added that `require` statement. Adding `tailwindcss` to my `package.json` (with `npm i tailwindcss`; note that I didn't install `tailwindcss` as a dev dependency) got things working locally. At this point I ran into the same issue you had deploying to Heroku, but adding the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack fixed things.