# webpack not found while deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuB5h.png)

I found some solutions online but nothing is working...
tried to remove webpack and add it again but still not working...
i also tried some other solutions but did not meet the solution

It's working fine locally problem occur when try to deploy on heroku.

Comment: First of all, by saying "I found to solutions online but nothing is working" we really don't know what you tried, so in the future try to explain it a little bit better. Second, you might need a nodejs buildpack on Heroku in order to run it, but it needs to be a primary buildpack. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76056631/10249627) that I wrote, it's not regarding Webpack directly but could be the same issue.